# What do you do if the rough in plumbing is supposed to stick out of the wall where you have two studs?

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a 48" floating cabinet and the sink
This is the manual of the cabinet I will install.
https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/VW4818-23WAL-127.pdf

The cabinet has slots for the ptrap and arm trap assembly but I am not sure if I can use a 45 degree elbow to avoid the collision with that group of three studs

There is no room to maneuver to the right or left of the cabinet as the shower glass door starts within 1" from the cabinet's left side as in the second picture
[image]

[image]
Here is a diagram for the drawers

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: Still waiting to find the time to resume this;got in trouble at work with a project and with an exam I need to pass asap
When I finish those and I resume this I will get back here. I have no solution for now Will have to figure it out when in place

Answer (score 1):

You have a large are you the left and right to bring the drain in it is quite common to run into studs not only on remodels but on new construction bring the drain up on the side that makes it easiest and use elbows to connect. The fewer bends the better but sometimes it takes a couple to get the job done.

Comment: that is my problem Ed, I can't turn left or right within the cabinet, it has tight slots for p trap and arm in the cabinets, constraining you to run these in a vertical plane so you can't turn left or right within the cabinet volume, see the manual please

Comment: minime, you may  have to modify the inside of the cabinet if there are shelves and dividers.  **Your link is PDF  and i am not going to download/open it**. Take a screen shot of the PDF and add the image to the question, or a photo of the cabinet itself.

Comment: done please see the update

Comment: I thought both drawers are like that. I might need to cut the second drawer the same way. I thought you guys are more experienced and you might have a nicer solution

Comment: Nicer than what ?   You can modify the drawer, Give up the storage space on one side or the the other.  Or modify the wall.

Comment: 24" (middle of the cabinet) falls 1" to the left of the group of three studs you see in the picture. I might be fine in the end>

Comment: I agree with Alaska man I don’t download files. 
The other way you can do this would be to put a header in cripples and king studs then bring the pipe up where you don’t need to modify the drawer/ cabinets but to me that is a lot of work. Framing is easy to adjust compared to premise cabinets but that is the other option I see.